# Sort odd numbers in array while keeping even numbers in place

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm working on a coding challenge to sort the odd elements of an array while keeping all even elements in their initial position.

I can sort the odd elements in groups between even elements while leaving the evens alone, but I want them to be ordered throughout the array. Here is my code:

```
def sort_array source_array
  return [] if source_array.empty?
  a = source_array
  n = a.length
  loop do
    swapped = false
    (n - 1).times do |i|
      if (a[i] > a[i + 1]) && a[i].odd? && a[i + 1].odd?
        a[i], a[i + 1] = a[i + 1], a[i]
        swapped = true
      end
    end
    break if not swapped
  end
  a
end

source_array = [7, 5, 35, 8, 12, 17, 47, 47, 37, 64, 22, 55, 13]
p sort_array(source_array)
# => [5, 7, 35, 8, 12, 17, 37, 47, 47, 64, 22, 13, 55]
```

Comment: do you have an example input and output?

Comment: If you get your program working, you will have successfully written a C program using Ruby syntax. If you really want to learn Ruby, look at more Ruby examples and try to write it more Ruby-esque. :) Ruby `Array` has a `sort` method which can do a `yield` to a block for any pair of elements it wants to compare. Research that and think about adding a new method to `Array`, maybe called `odd_sort` that will `yield` to a block only when you need to for the odd pair checks.

Comment: @emaillenin just added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways to do that.

```
arr = [7, 5, 35, 8, 12, 17, 47, 47, 37, 64, 22, 55, 13]
```

Both begin with the following calculation

```
odd, even = arr.each_with_index.partition { |n,i| n.odd? }
  #=> [[[7, 0], [5, 1], [35, 2], [17, 5], [47, 6], [47, 7], [37, 8], [55, 11], [13, 12]],
  #    [[8, 3], [12, 4], [64, 9], [22, 10]]]
odd
  #=> [[7, 0], [5, 1], [35, 2], [17, 5], [47, 6], [47, 7], [37, 8], [55, 11], [13, 12]]
even
  #=> [[8, 3], [12, 4], [64, 9], [22, 10]]
```

See [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), [Enumerable#partition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition) and [Integer#odd?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Integer.html#method-i-odd-3F).

**#1**

```
   odd_val, odd_idx = odd.transpose
     #=> [[7, 5, 35, 17, 47, 47, 37, 55, 13],
     #    [0, 1,  2,  5,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12]]
   a = even.concat(odd_val.sort.zip(odd_idx))
     #=> [[8, 3], [12, 4], [64, 9], [22, 10], [5, 0], [7, 1], [13, 2],
     #    [17, 5], [35, 6], [37, 7], [47, 8], [47, 11], [55, 12]]
   h = a.map(&:reverse).to_h
     #=> {3=>8, 4=>12, 9=>64, 10=>22, 0=>5, 1=>7, 2=>13, 5=>17, 6=>35, 7=>37,
     #    8=>47, 11=>47, 12=>55}
   h.values_at(*0..arr.size-1)
     #=> [5, 7, 13, 8, 12, 17, 35, 37, 47, 64, 22, 47, 55]
```

Note:

```
odd_val.sort.zip(odd_idx)
  #=> [5, 7, 13, 17, 35, 37, 47, 47, 55].zip([0, 1,  2,  5,  6,  7,  8, 11, 12])
  #=> [[5, 0], [7, 1], [13, 2], [17, 5], [35, 6], [37, 7], [47, 8], [47, 11], [55, 12]]
```

See [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-sort), [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) and  [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at).

**#2**

```
a = odd.map(&:first).sort
  #=> [5, 7, 13, 17, 35, 37, 47, 47, 55]
even.each { |n,i| a.insert(i,n) }
a #=> [5, 7, 13, 8, 12, 17, 35, 37, 47, 64, 22, 47, 55]
```

See [Array#insert](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-insert).

Comment: Wow that did the trick. That was way simpler than I was making it out to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach:

- Create an array with all odds (leaving source_array intact).  Sort
  this array.
- Consider source_array element by element. Is the
  element even then leave it . If it is odd, then replace it with the
  first element on the sorted odds list. Remove the first element of the
  sorted list.

Comment: Nice and clean, and short! I prefer it to my solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
source_array = [7, 5, 35, 8, 12, 17, 47, 47, 37, 64, 22, 55, 13]
odd_sorted = source_array.select(&:odd?).sort

source_array.map {|input| input.even? ? input : odd_sorted.shift }

# [5, 7, 13, 8, 12, 17, 35, 37, 47, 64, 22, 47, 55]
```

Comment: thats what I'm getting the desired output is: `[5, 7, 13, 8, 12, 17, 35, 37, 47,  64, 22, 47, 55]`

Comment: Your answer, after the edit, is the same as @steenslag's earlier answer.

Comment: Yeah my original answer outputs `[5, 7, 35, 8, 12, 17, 37, 47, 47, 64, 22, 13, 55]` which was same as OP's output. I asked for example output in the comments but OP posted his actual output. I mistook that for expected output and added the answer.